# Laravel Passport invalid refresh token - token is not linked to client

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I'm using Passport on Laravel 5.5, receiving error when trying to refresh access token - *only on production server* - local dev environment works fine!

This is the error returned:

```
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"message": "The refresh token is invalid.",
"hint": "Token is not linked to client"
}
```

I've verified that the tokens and clients exist on the database, are not expired, have not been revoked, are stored correctly etc.

Because the system is a multi-tenant system (with each tenant having it's own database) I did not create passport clients using the command

```
php artisan passport:client
```

instead I copied the passport `oauth_clients` table and contents for each tenant - so that each tenant uses the same client credentials for eg logging in from frontend, logging in from app (but with different endpoints).

I'm at a loss as to why it's working fine on my local machine but not production.

Does anyone know what exactly `php artisan passport:client` does besides creating a row in `oauth_clients` table?

I'm thinking that perhaps something more than just copying the `oauth_clients` table contents is needed..

Any advice appreciated! Thanks

Comment: share how you create refreshed token and where you stored this in local and resend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after digging around in vendor code I fixed the problem by modifying

> vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Grant/RefreshTokenGrant.php

function validateOldRefreshToken

changed

```
if ($refreshTokenData['client_id'] !== $clientId) {
        $this->getEmitter()->emit(new RequestEvent(RequestEvent::REFRESH_TOKEN_CLIENT_FAILED, $request));
        throw OAuthServerException::invalidRefreshToken('Token is not linked to client');
    }
```

to

```
if ($refreshTokenData['client_id'] != $clientId) {
        $this->getEmitter()->emit(new RequestEvent(RequestEvent::REFRESH_TOKEN_CLIENT_FAILED, $request));
        throw OAuthServerException::invalidRefreshToken('Token is not linked to client');
    }
```

even though $clientId was matching, the function is passed a string (as required) but the $refreshTokenData['client_id'] is an integer.

fml.

Answer (score 0):

The message: "The refresh token is invalid" seems misleading in the case OP described. Actually, this exception is raised while type checking of passed client_id param. For me the datatype of the passed param (client_id) was string. Which should be a number(int) instead.

Changing following

```
client_id: "2"
```

To

```
client_id: 2
```

resolved my issue.

Note: It is not recommended to alter the Vendor. Instead please look for the client_id parameter's datatype in payload.